# <random> include not to be found in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, random, include

Does anyone have a solution for the fact that I cannot find my  include in Eclipse? /Applications/Xcode.app/etc and /usr/livm-gcc-4.2/lib/etc are greyed out, might be the problem but I do not know how to fix this.

Comment: AFAIK `<random>` is new in C++11, gcc 4.2 seems a bit old. Are you sure it even has it? You might need to upgrade.

Comment: I was under the impression that Xcode would cover it. Might a fix of the Xcode includes solve this?